# Mysql File Import Issue When Use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in column

Tags: mysql

I have a table which use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as a default value on column. table working fine. but when export the database and then again import the exported mysql file, then the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column replace all date with current today datetime.

This is the table srtructure:

```
CREATE TABLE a ( 
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    col0 varchar(5) NOT NULL , 
    col1 varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    col2 varchar(20) , 
    col3 varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    createDateTime timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=7430 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: What is definition of your table?

Comment: What method you use to import & export?

Comment: please clarify us your export and import method and the tool you are using for export and import.

Comment: use mysql cmd OR phpmyadmin
CREATE TABLE a ( 
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
col0 varchar(5) NOT NULL ,
col1 varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
col2 varchar(20) , 
col3 varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
createDateTime timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7430 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 1):

Just replace createDateTime timestamp with createDateTime datetime

Answer (score -1):

I can say that the problem is here:

```
CREATE TABLE a ( 
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    col0 varchar(5) NOT NULL , 
    col1 varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    col2 varchar(20) , 
    col3 varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    createDateTime timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, <--- **Here
    PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=7430 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Since you define the `createDateTime` column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default, whenever there's changes on the row data, the column would update itself.

I experienced this once when I was doing an app and I put my `createdDate` column as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default similar as you. Then I realize that every time I made changes on some information through the app, the column also get updated to the current timestamp; which ultimately made my data all messed up!

I think what you can do from the exported file (sql dump) is:

1. Open the dump file using a text editor - (caveat: if the dump file is too large, might not be easy to open.)
2. Locate the `CREATE TABLE` syntax in the dump file then change the following:

```
CREATE TABLE a ( 
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    col0 varchar(5) NOT NULL , 
    col1 varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    col2 varchar(20) , 
    col3 varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    createDateTime timestamp NOT NULL, <--- **Here
    PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=7430 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

3. Save the dump file and try importing it.

If that doesn't work, I suggest:

1. Create another table using the `CREATE TABLE` with modified `createDateTime` column above - name it as `a1` or `a_copy` etc.
2. Run `INSERT` query from table A like :

```
INSERT INTO a_copy SELECT * FROM a;
```

3. Check if data matches between the two table - I usually run a `LEFT JOIN` query for a quick check like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a_copy.id FROM a 
LEFT JOIN a_copy
   ON a.id=a_copy.id 
   AND a.col0=a_copy.col0
   AND a.col1=a_copy.col1
   AND a.col2=a_copy.col2
   AND a.col3=a_copy.col3
   AND a.createDateTime=a_copy.createDateTime
WHERE a_copy.id IS NULL;
```

*The `ON` condition can be just `ON a.id=a_copy.id AND a.createDateTime=a_copy.createDateTime` and `WHERE a_copy.id IS NULL` is just simply showing any result that doesn't match.

4. Once you're satisfied, export and import the `a_copy` table.